# Hadoop upload files from local machine to amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hadoop, hdfs

I am working on a Java MapReduce app that has to be able to provide an upload service for some pictures from the local machine of the user to an S3 bucket.

The thing is the app must run on an EC2 cluster, so I am not sure how I can refer to the local machine when copying the files. The method copyFromLocalFile(..) needs a path from the local machine which will be the EC2 cluster...

I'm not sure if I stated the problem correctly, can anyone understand what I mean?

Thanks

Comment: What's not clear here is how the user (from whose local machine you want to upload the images) is interacting with this app.  Can you share any more architecture details?

Answer (score 1):

You might also investigate s3distcp: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html

Apache DistCp is an open-source tool you can use to copy large amounts of data. DistCp uses MapReduce to copy in a distributed manner—sharing the copy, error handling, recovery, and reporting tasks across several servers. S3DistCp is an extension of DistCp that is optimized to work with Amazon Web Services, particularly Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). Using S3DistCp, you can efficiently copy large amounts of data from Amazon S3 into HDFS where it can be processed by your Amazon Elastic MapReduce (Amazon EMR) job flow. You can also use S3DistCp to copy data between Amazon S3 buckets or from HDFS to Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the files from the userMachine to at least 1 node before you will be able to use them through a MapReduce.

The `FileSystem` and `FileUtil` functions refer to paths either on the `HDFS` or the local disk of one of the nodes in the cluster.
It cannot reference the user's local system. (Maybe if you did some ssh setup... maybe?)